# Should I assign a range outside of a loop in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I realize that Python isn't the most performant language, but since this seems like it would be easy, I'm wondering whether it's worthwhile to move a range assignment outside of a for loop if I have nested loops. For example:

```
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        foo()
```

versus

```
r = range(1000)
for i in range(1000):
    for j in r:
        foo()
```

Will the second one run faster, or will the Python interpreter optimize out the repeated function call in the first example? Also, does the answer change if I were to use xrange? (or Python 3 range). Thanks!

Comment: Are they the same? Yes. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on @Hrvoje's answer, here are my benchmarks:

```
import timeit

NUM_ITERATIONS = 5000
NUM_BENCHMARKS = 50

def a():
    x = 0
    for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for j in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
            x+=1
    return x

def b():
    x = 0
    r = range(NUM_ITERATIONS)
    for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for j in r:
            x+=1
    return x

def c():
    x = 0
    r1 = range(NUM_ITERATIONS)
    r2 = range(NUM_ITERATIONS)
    for i in r1:
        for j in r2:
            x+=1
    return x

def d():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for j in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
            x += 1
    return x

def e():
    x = 0
    r = xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS)
    for i in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for j in r:
            x += 1
    return x

print "A: %.4f" % (timeit.timeit(a, number=NUM_BENCHMARKS))
print "B: %.4f" % (timeit.timeit(b, number=NUM_BENCHMARKS))
print "C: %.4f" % (timeit.timeit(c, number=NUM_BENCHMARKS))
print "D: %.4f" % (timeit.timeit(d, number=NUM_BENCHMARKS))
print "E: %.4f" % (timeit.timeit(e, number=NUM_BENCHMARKS))
```

Results:

```
A: 81.5383
B: 71.2025
C: 69.2143
D: 94.8806
E: 93.1961
```

Very much as expected. No real difference in using `xrange` as it's returning a generator. Slight benefit of predefining the range variable.

Comment: Selected as the answer because it covered the difference between predefinition and defining in the loop, as well as the difference between range and xrange, as requested. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in Python 2 `range` will allocate the memory for the whole list and that could lead to massive memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see:

```
@timeit
def a():
    x = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            x+=1
    return x

@timeit
def b():
    x = 0
    r = range(10000)
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in r:
            x+=1
    return x

a()
b()

'a' ((), {}) 3.30 sec
'b' ((), {}) 2.64 sec
```

So yes, the second one appears faster.

Comment: now try with `xrange`  instead of `range` in (a) and it will get even faster, because no lists get allocated.

Comment: When discussing `range` performance I generally assume Python 3, as Python 2's `range`/`xrange` are non-performant almost by default.

Comment: I'd like to see the results of replacing `for j in range_object: x+=1` with just `range_object` to eliminate the noise from iterating through the range and incrementing the counter, since all we're really interested in is the creation or reuse of those `range` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The results I got were quite inconclusive

```
In [1]: def f():
   ...:     for i in range(1000):
   ...:             for j in range(1000):
   ...:                     pass
   ...:         

In [2]: def g():
   ...:     r = range(1000)
   ...:     for i in range(1000):
   ...:             for j in r:
   ...:                     pass
   ...:         

In [3]: import itertools

In [4]: def h():
   ...:     for i in itertools.product(range(1000),range(1000)):
   ...:         pass

In [6]: timeit f()
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop

In [7]: timeit g()
10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop

In [8]: timeit h()
10 loops, best of 3: 38.3 ms per loop
```

I suppose the moral of this story is "don't use itertools, that one's slower"

(Python 3, so range is a generator here)

Comment: Python 3's `range` isn't a generator, it's a special object with additional logic. It isn't consumed when iterated through, it doesn't need to be iterated through to perform basic operations like `in`, and so on.